# Building for iOS 5 iPad 1 on Xcode 5

Tags: ios, ipad, xcode5

I'm attempting to build a universal app for iOS 5-7 using Xcode 5 and Mac OSX 10.8.4.
Works on iOS 6 and 7 like a charm, but when I run on my iPad 1 with iOS 5.1 it immediately crashes presumably before even reaching main()

The stack trace is the following:

```
0 cr_detectClasses
1 call_load_methods
2 load_images
3 dyld::notifySingle(dyld_image_states, ImageLoader const*)
4 ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&)
5 ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&)
6 dyld::initializeMainExecutable()
7 dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**)
8 dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*)
```

What's going on and is there any way around this?

Comment: whats your deployment target? 5.0?

Comment: Most likely you have added a required framework that doesn't exist in iOS 5. You need to make the guilty framework optional.